# Relative Layout inside a ScrollView - Not scrolling

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I have a relative layout as child of Scrollview. I already tried a bunch of answers in here but the scroll isn't working.

That's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/home_bg_branco" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_categoria"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/home_placeholder_slider"
            android:src="@drawable/home_placeholder_slider"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/home_imageswitcher_slider_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewCategoria"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/home_imageswitcher_slider_listview"
            tools:ignore="NestedScrolling" >
        </ListView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoria_cores_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_cores"
            android:src="@drawable/img_cores" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoria_destaque_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/categoria_placeholder_slider_listview"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img_destaques"
            android:src="@drawable/img_destaques" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Another thing: i disabled the listview scroll to avoid conflicts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Afaik you need to put either the scrollview into a table layout or a table layout instead relative inside scrollview.

Comment: @icbytes table layout? Sorry, im not understanding your position.

Comment: Read about vertical scrollviews. Most posts refer to a table layout

Answer (score 0):

You should change `layout_height` of the `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_categoria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
```

Also remove `android:fillViewport="true"` from `ScrollView`.

In my project I have several `ScrollView`s exactly like this, and they work fine:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
```

**UPDATE**
One last thing I can propose is to remove `ListView` from the `ScrollView` as it can interfere with layout and scrolling.

Comment: @MarcoTulio have you tried removing `fillViewport` as well?

Comment: @MarcoTulio and if you remove `ListView`?

Comment: I can't remove ListView it's part of my objective in this layout. And even removing it i had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your onCreate()

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```